# How to handle multiple pathflows without making the user choose?

Tags: user-centered-design, workflow

I'm building an app where there's a subscription fee to create projects, but their team members can join for free.

[image: Users need to choose if they want to create projects or join projects]

I had a user stuck in this screen wrong for so long, where they kept clicking on "Only Join Existing Projects" and then had to tell them that they have to choose "Create and join projects"

How do I overcome this problem without having the user choose?

[image]

This screen appears if they choose option 1 and

[image]

and the pricing screen appears if they choose option 2.

I'm seeing a couple of potential fixes.

1. Take the user directly to a create/join projects screen and if they click on "join" it'll allow them for free, if they click on "create" it asks them to confirm a pricing plan first.
2. Keep the user for free, until a project is created (but the user wouldn't know (?) they're starting to get charged?)
3. If users by mistake, choose "Only join projects" link the other screen with a button that says "Want to create a new project instead?"

Do let me know how to approach this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that both inputs are at the same level. I don't know what the marketing strategy of the company is, but if it were mine, I would be more interested in catching new members (with their corresponding fees) and secondly, that current users interact with their projects to maintain the rhythm and health of the site.

Many service sites tend to place the access to new members as the main element in the center of the page and the login in a secluded corner. The example of the image is the [netlify.com](https://www.netlify.com/) main screen where you can clearly see the invitation to participate in the site <kbd>Get started...</kbd> and in the upper right corner the <kbd>Sign up</kbd> button, more prominent since it's about new members, and <kbd>Sign in</kbd> in second (or third) visual order, either because former members already know the site's interface or because they are not the marketing priority (or both).

[image: netlify]

As I deduce from what is described in the question, the site doesn't have a login, but a project code to enter existing projects. Personally, I would give a (hugely) different visual hierarchy to both elements for the reasons described:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I love the idea of hierarchy of the elements!